# Como passar dados de um input para outro com HTML e Python?

Tags: html, python, django

Galera, estou com um problema na minha aplicação e não consigo encontrar a solução na internet.

Estou fazendo uma aplicação web na qual preciso pegar algumas informações do usuário e para melhorar a experiencia, estou separando o formulário em várias páginas e me deparo com o problema de não conseguir identificar o id de cadastro das informações do html anterior.

Já pensei em pegar estas informação passando id de referencia na url, mas acho que não seria uma boa solução devido aos problemas de segurança.

Neste caso, o melhor seria passar o id criptografado na url ou teria alguma maneira de passar este id para a próxima página?

Segue partes do código para que sejam utilizadas como referência:

Primeira parte do formulário:

```html
<form method="POST" action="segurado/">
  {% csrf_token %}
  Nome completo:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nome" maxlength="100" required=""><br> Sexo:

  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="genero" value="masculino" checked> Masculino
  <input type="radio" name="genero" value="feminino"> Feminino<br> e-mail:

  <br>
  <input type="email" name="e-mail" maxlength="50" required=""><br> Telefone:

  <br>
  <input type="tel" name="telefone" maxlength="30" required=""><br>

  <input type="submit">

</form>
```

View que o input faz requisição após o preenchimento e envio do fomulário, a mesma faz o cadastro no banco de dados e pede as próximas informações:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    # verificando se existe algum telefone ja cadastrado
    try:
        telefone['numero'] = str(request.POST.get('telefone'))
        Telefone.objects.get(numero=telefone['numero'])
    except Exception as e:
        mensagem['mensagem_telefone'] = str(e)

        # cadastrando o telefone caso seja a primeira vez
        try:
            Telefone.objects.create(**telefone)
        except Exception as e:
            mensagem['mensagem_telefone2'] = str(e)
        else:
            mensagem['mensagem_telefone2'] = "Cadastro Realizado"
    else:
        mensagem['mensagem_telefone'] = "Ja cadastrado"

    # verificando se tem algum email cadastrado
    try:
        email['email'] = request.POST.get('e-mail')
        Email.objects.get(email=email['email'])
    except Exception as e:
        mensagem['mensagem_email'] = str(e)

        # cadastrando caso seja o primeiro e-mail
        try:
            Email.objects.create(**email)
        except Exception as e:
            mensagem['mensagem_email2'] = str(e)
        else:
            mensagem['mensagem_email2'] = "Cadastro Realizado"
    else:
        mensagem['mensagem_email'] = "Ja cadastrado"

    # realizando o cadastro do Usuario
    try:
        usuario['nome'] = request.POST.get('nome')
        usuario['genero'] = request.POST.get('genero')
        novo_usuario = Usuario.objects.create(**usuario)
    except Exception as e:
        mensagem['mensagem_usuario'] = e
    else:
        mensagem['mensagem_usuario'] = "cadastro realizado com sucesso"

        # realizando o cadastro do email
        try:
            email = request.POST.get('e-mail')
            cadastro = Email.objects.get(email=email)
            novo_usuario.emails.add(cadastro)
        except Exception as e:
            mensagem['mensagem_email3'] = str(e)
        else:
            mensagem['mensagem_email3'] = "Cadastro do email no cliente realizado com sucesso"

        # realizando o cadastro do telefone
        try:
            telefone = request.POST.get('telefone')
            cadastro = Telefone.objects.get(numero=telefone)
            novo_usuario.telefones.add(cadastro)
        except Exception as e:
            mensagem['mensagem_telefone3'] = str(e)
        else:
            mensagem['mensagem_telefone3'] = "Cadastro do telefone no cliente realizado com sucesso"

    return render(request, 'cotacao/segurado.html')

else:
    return redirect('cotacao_usuario')
```

Página Html da segunda parte do formulário:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/cotacao/veiculo/">

  {% csrf_token %} CPF/CNPJ:

  <br>
  <input type="text" name="cpf/cnpj" required><br> Data de Nascimento:<br>
  <input type="date" name="nascimento" required><br>

  <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Prosseguir">

</form>
```

Ai me deparo com o problema de saber como que terei o Id do primeiro cadastro para continuar o cadastro das demais informações no meu banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use uma variável de sessão para armazenar o id:

```
request.session['id_cadastro'] = algum_tipo_de_id
```

depois na outra página você pode ler o id

```
id_atual = request.session.get('id_cadastro', None)
if not id_atual:
    # chegou sem ter passado pela primeira parte do form, redireciona
    return redirect('pagina1')
...
```

O django vai gerenciar tudo pra você, vai criar um cookie de sessão temporário independente para cada cliente, e usar esse cookie para resgatar os dados específicos de cada sessão em andamento e disponibilizar na variável `request.session`, sendo que os dados que você armazenar nela nunca são enviados para o cliente, ficam somente no servidor.